# Is there a faster way to loop through the installed applications on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, file-management

I'm writing a menu bar extra that shows you a list of your installed apps and allows you to click on each button in the list to open that app. Obviously, to do this I need a list of every app the user has. The specific way I chose to do this was making a function that would loop through the files in the system's Applications folder, strip out anything in an app's contents or that didn't end in .app, and return an array containing a list of files as names, which is then iterated through to create a list of "app buttons" that the user can click on to launch the app.

The code for my function is

```
func enumerateAppsFolder() -> Array<String> {
    var fileNames:Array<String> = []
    
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let enumerator:FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath:"/Applications/")!
    
    while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        if element.hasSuffix("app") && !element.contains("Contents") { // checks the extension
            fileNames.append(element)
        }
    }
    return fileNames
}
```

And I create my list with

```
ForEach(enumerateAppsFolder(), id:\.self){
    AppBarMenuItem(itemAppName: $0)
}
```

But when I do it like that, the result is what I expected, but the performance is horrible. This can be seen in the screenshot, and will just be made worse by larger applications folders on some people's systems
[image: Screenshot of bad app performance]
(When the app is starting up, which takes about 5 minutes, the CPU and disk usage are also extremely high)
Is there a better and faster method that will retrieve every app on the system, similarly to the macOS launchpad or "Open With.." list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `enumerator` method of `FileManager` that you are using performs a deep enumeration of the file tree. You don't want a deep enumeration, just a top-level enumeration. Use the version of the `enumerator` method that has the `options` parameter and pass in `.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants`.

Here's an updated version of your function getting a `URL` directly from `FileManager` for the Applications folder and then doing a shallow enumeration to get the list of apps.

```
func enumerateAppsFolder() -> [String] {
    var appNames = [String]()

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let appsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .localDomainMask).first {
        if let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: appsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants) {
            while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL {
                if element.pathExtension == "app" { // checks the extension
                    appNames.append(element.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return appNames
}

print(enumerateAppsFolder())
```

Sample output when run from a Swift Playground:

> "Numbers", "Dropbox", "Xcode", "Apple Configurator 2", "iMovie"

Comment: This worked great! It retrieved everything in the Applications folder with a time of only a few milliseconds. While this answer works fine, I'll see if anyone else finds a way to list the apps more similarly to how system information, launchpad, etc. lists them.

Comment: In what way are you looking for different output? Give a specific example.

Comment: Something like how Launchpad lists apps. I know how to make a list of apps, but I don't know how to retrieve the apps in the way it does.

Comment: Again, give a clear specific example of what you mean. Are you asking about showing the apps with icons in a grid or something else? Again, be specific.

Comment: I meant displaying every app the user has installed in a list. Launchpad shows folders and groups of apps, and it seems to search for apps in multiple locations. I was looking to know how it does that.

Comment: You will note in the code I posted the use of `.localDomainMask`. That gets apps from `/Applications`. If you run that with `.userDomainMask` you get apps from `~/Applications`. You may also need to add a check to see if a returned app URL is actually a folder (such as Utilities) and perform a search in that folder as well. Perhaps that is what you are looking for.